# Compound beans in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, ioc-container

Suppose I have my own bean which contains another beans hardcoded.

How to join this with Spring configuration?

First way is to use factory-method:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="myClass1"/>
<bean id="bean1.member" factory-bean="bean1" factory-method="getMember"/>
<bean id="bean2" class="myClass2">
   <property name="collaborator" ref="bean1.member"/>
</bean>
```

Another way is to use EL:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="myClass1"/>
<bean id="bean2" class="myClass2">
   <property name="collaborator" value="#{bean1.member}"/>
</bean>
```

In latter case Spring does not realize the dependency. Anyway, Bean Graph in Eclipse displays beans unrelated.

Are there better ways? May be I may implement some interface with `MyClass1` so that it will treated as container or context?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separate bean for `bean1.member` and inject it into `bean1`

```
<bean id="bean3previouslyMember" class="myCompoundBean"/>

<bean id="bean1" class="myClass1">
   <property name="member" ref="bean3previouslyMember"/>
</bean>
<bean id="bean2" class="myClass2">
   <property name="collaborator" ref="bean3previouslyMember"/>
</bean>
```

Unless myClass1 is not modifiable and has no setter, this is generally what we do.